# Assistance with PHP and HTML Email syntax

Tags: php, html-email

I think its plainly obvious what Im trying to do here.

$message is the message param from wp_mail().

I need this foreach loop to run inside my email to get all the dynamic values from a form.

```
   $tmp = '';
    $i = 0;      
        foreach( $_POST as $key => $value)  {
            if( substr( $key, 0, 14) == 'course-select-')   {
                $tmp = '<tr><td>Day number' . $i . ' :</td><td> ' . $value . '</td></tr>';
            }
        $i++;
    };


   //construct the email
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Booking Confirmation Part 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>Booking Confirmation Part 2 : ' . $golfersname . '</h2>
      <table width="500">
        <tr>
          <td>Accomodation</td>
          <td>' . $accomodation . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Singles</td>
          <td>' . $singles . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doubles</td>
          <td>' . $doubles . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Car Type</td>
          <td>' . $cartype . '</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
          <td>Course Details</td>
        </tr>       
        ' . $tmp . '
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';
```

Everything breaks from the moment it hits the `'. $i = 0;` . What real stupid thing am I missing out on?

The foreach does work as I’ve tested it already in my console.

Thanks

Comment: It's useless to use loops while concatenating strings.

Comment: As Ive found out. Although Ive got this working, but it only prints the first iteration.

Comment: Because you overwrite `$tmp` on each iteration. Append to it.

Comment: You're **NOT** concatenating. you just keep trashing $tmp with a new value each time.

Answer (score 0):

"." are used to build STRINGS in PHP. It seems you are trying to execute code (i.e. the loop and the assignment to $i) halfway through your string. This does not make sense at all.

The best way to do this would be:

```
$message = "<HTML>....Course details";
$i = 0;     
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value)
{
  if( substr( $key, 0, 14) == 'course-select-')
  {
       $message=$message.'Day number' . $i . ' : ' . $value;
  }
  $i++;
}
$message=$message."</TD>...</HTML>";
```

Then complete your email script.

**EDIT**

Yes you have now addressed the first issue. The reason it is only showing the first result is because you are reassigning $tmp in your loop. See below:

```
$tmp = '<tr><td>...'
```

should be

```
$tmp = $tmp.'<tr><td>...'
```

Answer (score 0):

in php you can combine assignment operators (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

in this case you can combine . and = to make .=

when you are looping your foreach change

```
$tmp = '<tr><td>Day number'.....
```

to

```
$tmp .= '<tr><td>Day number' ....
```

this will add the string on each new loop to your string.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$tmp = '';
$i = 0;      
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $value)  {
        if( substr( $key, 0, 14) == 'course-select-')   {
            $tmp.= '<tr><td>Day number' . $i . ' :</td><td> ' . $value . '</td></tr>';
        }
    $i++;
};
```